# Read and parse JSON-like string file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Don't know how to deal with this JSON-like string file in python (Not exactly JSON, but don't what's the format for it).

```
file = '''
data_structure {

key: "A"    
arg {
    name: "A1"
    type { type: STRING }
    function: "A1-1"
    examples: "apple1"
    examples: "apple2"
    }
arg {
    name: "A2"
    type { type: STRING }
    function: "A2-1"
    examples: "grape1"
    examples: "grape2"
    }
    description: "ALL"
}

data_structure {

key: "C"
type { type: STRING }
arg {
    name: "C1"
    function: "C1-1"
    examples: "cake1"
    examples: "cake2"
    }
}
'''
```

Is there any way to parse it like Object somehow as below?

```
file_a = open(file, "rt").read()
// file_a = convert(file_a)
print(list(file_a.data_structure.key))

result: ["A", "C"]
```

Comment: The data structure format is different... for first datastructure the`type{}`is in inside of `args{}` and second one it isn't ...??? so there is no specific format or is it just a typo???

Comment: IMLE.  I think you have to use regex expressions to reformat the data into json format...